# Why isn't it possible to use prepared statements (based on ALTER TABLE) to set default values of MySQL fields from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, alter-table

I'm writing PHP code to change the default value of a varchar field in a MySQL database. In order for the code to be secure, I use a prepared statement, but for some reason it is seemingly impossible to get PHP/MySQL to accept this in this particular situation, why is that?

(I'm using PHP 5.5.11)

Here is the code using prepared statements, which does NOT work (the mysqli_stmt_execute() call returns null, and the default value of the field remains unaltered):

```
$new_field_default_value = 'test';
$field_modification_sql_command = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn SET DEFAULT ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db_conn_handle);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $field_modification_sql_command);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $new_field_default_value);
$temp_db_res = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Here is the (insecure) code using concatenation and pure query execution, which DOES work (the mysqli_query() call returns true, and the default value of the field is indeed altered):

```
$new_field_default_value = 'test';
$field_modification_sql_command = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn SET DEFAULT '" . $new_field_default_value . "'";
$temp_db_res = mysqli_query($db_conn_handle, $field_modification_sql_command);
```

Could anyone possibly tell me why it does not work to use prepared statements here, and what I need to change (if possible at all?) to make it work with a prepared statement?

Comment: Where is the value of `$new_field_default_value` coming from? That is to say, is that value coming from a trustworthy or untrustworthy source?

Comment: It is coming from a NOT trustworthy source (an HTTP parameter), the code above is just simplified for the example here, so yes, I do need a prepared statement (and either way I'm still interested in why these won't work in this situation!).

Comment: It might be an issue with the `mysqli` driver. Perhaps try it using `PDO`? Also, you should try using a prepared statement directly using [the SQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to make sure it's possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) about prepared statements:

> In general, parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

So, bind parameter in DDL prepared statement should not work. I think you'll need to validate the parameter with `preg_match` to execute through the "insecure" way.

Comment: That's specifically mentioned in the `mysqli::prepare()` docs. The corresponding `PDO::prepare()` docs don't mention it at all.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax I have adjusted the link reference to the correct method been invoked to prepare the statement.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I know when I'm using DML statements and when I'm using DDL statements, is there any simple way to tell them apart? Or is it just something like "if the operation affects database/table structure in any way, it's DDL, and if not, it's DML"?

Comment: They're [listed in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html), but basically DML is select, insert, update and delete, and almost everything else is DDL.

Comment: Oh, and about your mention of preg_match(), wouldn't mysqli_real_escape_string() be even better?

Comment: For sure `mysqli_real_escape_string` must be applied, but it works in escaping special characters, while with `preg_match` you will be validating if the submitted value is an expected value.

Comment: You do not need to use prepared statements usually for DDL Statements, There is no need to prepare anything if you are not using user input & you most certainly should not for DDL

Comment: FWIW I removed this part from the docs. It was incorrect information copied from MySQL documentation. AFAIK you can use prepared statements with DDL.